# Invalid conversion from and to void * when using ibpp in c++

Tags: c++, casting, firebird

One of my class members has `void *` type:

```
void * conn;
```

In `Connection` method I set connection to `Firebird` database and set `conn` member like this:

```
IBPP::Database conn = IBPP::DatabaseFactory(host, dbname, user, pass);
conn->Connect();
this->conn = static_cast<void *>(conn);
```

This way of doing things works well for other multiple databases, but breaks when I try to use it with `Firebird`. So, this is what happens. In another method I use `conn` member to fetch data from a particular database. When it comes to `Firebird`, I do it like this:

```
IBPP::Transaction tr = IBPP::TransactionFactory(static_cast<IBPP::Database>(this->conn));
```

However, this line of code results in an error message:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'void *' to 'IBPP::IDatabase *'
```

I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT**

Here are some code snippets from `ibpp.h`:

```
...
class IDatabase;
typedef Ptr<IDatabase> Database;
...
class IDatabase{
    public:
        virtual const char * ServerName() const = 0;
        virtual const char * DatabaseName() const = 0;
        ...
        virtual void Connect() = 0;
        ...
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is a reproducible testcase:

```
#define IBPP_LINUX
#include <ibpp.h>

int main(){
    //#1. No errors
    IBPP::Database conn = IBPP::DatabaseFactory("localhost","/var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/reestr.fdb","SYSDBA","root");
    conn->Connect();
    conn->Disconnect();
    //end of #1.
    //#2. Here we get errors.
    void * cn;
    IBPP::Database conn2 = IBPP::DatabaseFactory("localhost","/var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/reestr.fdb","SYSDBA","root");
    conn2->Connect();
    cn = static_cast<void *>(conn2);
    conn2->Disconnect();
    return 0;
}
```

and this is the error message, that I get when I try to compile it:

```
error: invalid static_cast from type IBPP::Database 
{aka IBPP::Ptr<IBPP::IDatabase>} to type void *
```

The error message points to this line of code:

```
cn = static_cast<void *>(conn2);
```

Comment: Did you try `reinterpret_cast<IBPP::Database>(this->conn)` ?

Comment: No, I did not try that. I will check it now.

Comment: @SergeBallesta it should be `reinterpret_cast<IBPP::Database*>(this->conn)` but yeah, that's the idea.

Comment: `this->conn = static_cast<void *>(conn);` -- `conn` is not a pointer, what does this line do ?

Comment: @ thirtythreeforty. No, Serge Ballesta  is right.

Comment: well, guys, please, pay attention to the fact that `IBPP::Database` is a typedef of `IBPP::IDatabase *`

Comment: Ohh, that's confusing.  Yeah then Serge's is right.

Comment: But' unfortunatelly, `reinterpret_cast` does not help. I still get the same error message. I really wonder what can be so special about `IBPP::Database` pointer.

Comment: Perhaps there's something else that's missing in the code snippet? Can you try this: "void * dummy = nullptr; IPBB::Database conn = static_cast<IPBB::Database>(dummy);" - and see if it yields the same result (compilation error)?

Comment: I prefer it does not work : I've verified and  `T x; T *p = static_cast<T*>(static_cast<void *>(&x));` is valid. I suppose that you have a const or volatile problem. A C style cast should work (`(IBPP::Database) this-> conn`), but it would be **better** to find where the problem comes from.

Comment: @Jacobian, can you also provide the exact type declaration of `TPBB::IDatabase`? If it contains any special modifiers (alignment, const/volatile, __restrict, etc.) that may shed some light on the issue.

Comment: @UnknownGosu To answer this, I have to dive into the source code of IBPP library. Give me some time and I will try to post it.

Comment: @Serge Ballesta. Do you mean, that you managed to make it work?

Comment: @SergeBallesta, isn't reinterpret_cast same a C-style cast except for const-ness part, though? I think straight C cast might be a UB in this case, even if it compiles (the idea is that if reinterpret_cast doesn't work, there's some edge case to uncover, e.g. source pointer type could be larger than void *, for instance, if it's a pointer to member function [not this case, just to illustrate the idea]).

Comment: @Jacobian Unfortunately I do not use IBPP - that's why I only give comments and not an answer ;-)

Comment: @UnknownGosu: I agree with you : without knowing why normal cast does not work I would not dare to do the C style cast...

Comment: @Jacobian, can you post a minimal reproducible example?  I can't see anything suspicious so far (btw, thanks for the question update).
Ideally, it should be looking like this:
`#include ...
struct foo { void * bar; };
int main() { foo f = {}; IBPP::Database db = static_cast<IBPP::Database>(f.bar);
}
`
 or something like that. We ought to localize the problem as narrowly as possible.

Comment: I need some time to prepare it. With all relative information - like compilation and linkage flags etc.

Comment: You need to post a reproducible testcase instead of making us guess!

Comment: I will post it in a minute. Totally reproducible testcase.

Comment: Here it is. The reproducible testcase. I can even post Makefile, if you wish.

Comment: Your reproducer seems like a different issue entirely to me.

Comment: @ hvd But related as close as possible. It seems like there is some conversion problem in both directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a comment you say:

> well, guys, please, pay attention to the fact that `IBPP::Database` is a typedef of `IBPP::IDatabase *`

No it isn't.

Look again:

```
error: invalid static_cast from type IBPP::Database
{aka IBPP::Ptr<IBPP::IDatabase>}
```

It's a typedef for **`Ptr<IDatabase>`**, not `IDatabase*`, so it is a smart pointer, and not convertible to `void*`

See http://www.ibpp.org/reference/guidelines#ibpp_smart_pointers_reference

Comment: That was my guess in a comment. Thanks!

Comment: You are saying that it is not convertibe. But is there any workaround? Like using `release` or `move` methods?

Comment: The problem is that if the last smart pointer goes away while you still have the `void*` the pointer becomes invalid. You can probably use `intf()` to get the raw pointer and manually increase the ref-count on the object, then manually decrease the ref-count when you're finished with it ... but that could be error-prone.